# InstaPaper API - /api/1/bookmarks/get_text

Tags: php, api, instapaper

I'm working the InstaPaper API

I'm using this string to pull the content of the article.

```
$Bookmark_Text = $connection->getBookmarkText($Bookmark['bookmark_id']);
```

Unfortunately it is pulling the entire html and basically putting the HTML structure in my HTML.

Example.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <html>
    <head>Instapaper Title</head>
    <body>InstaPaper Article Content</body>
    </html>
</body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts on how to just get "Instapaper article content"

Thanks!

Comment: What language are you calling the API with? PHP?

Comment: Yes PHP. Will add to the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s some JS code that extracts only the article and removes Instapaper’s stuff (top and bottom bar for example).

`html.replace(/^[\s\S]*<div id="story">|<\/div>[^<]*<div class="bar bottom">[\s\S]*$/gim, '');`

Be aware that it may change as Instapaper’s HTML output changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parser to extract the contents of `<body>`. [PHP has some built in](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php), but there are [others](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) out there which might be easier to use.

This should do it if `$Bookmark_Text` is a valid HTML document.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($Bookmark_Text);
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
$content = $body->ownerDocument->saveHTML($body);
```

Comment: None of these seem to be able to pull just everything in the body.

Comment: Are you sure the HTML in your example is exactly what's returned by the API? I was able to create an example using `DOMDocument`, but because the `<head>` has text in it, that's parsed as a `<p>` and put into the body.

Comment: added my code to the answer. If the returned document isn't valid HTML, maybe your only choice is trying a regular expression